# Json data to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I take data in a json file given like this:

```
Ticker,Quandl Code,Name
STI,GOOG/NYSE_STI,SunTrust Banks 
AAPL,GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL,Apple Inc
```

and turn it into an array like this:

```
var stocks = [
    ["STI,GOOG/NYSE_STI,SunTrust Banks"],
    ["AAPL,GOOG/NASDAQ_AAPL,Apple Inc"]
];
```

Comment: That is not a JSON format that you are working with. It appears to be CSV

Answer (score 4):

Your input is in CSV, not JSON. The following question has a function that converts CSV for an array:

[Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
var myarray = [];
var myJSON = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var item = {
        "value": i,
        "label": i
    };
    myarray.push(item);
}
myJSON = JSON.stringify({myarray: myarray});

alert(myJSON);
```

Comment: Insert this code in console fire fox and run then you can see result.